# SpringBootTest fail if application contains @KafkaListener annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I create a new spring boot project with a simple test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

When I run this test it succeeds. But If I add any method annotated `@KafkaListener` annotation to any service:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "v-group")
public void test(){
  log.info("test");
}
```

And run test, It works sometimes and throws an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with your kafka configuration, perhaps mis-matched SSL properties; you need to show the application.yml (or .properties).

Comment: @ Gary Russell  I have empty `application.yml `. Need I have a correct config to Kafka if I run a unit test and I not test Kafka?

Comment: By default, we try to connect to kafka on `localhost:9092`. You either need a real broker or use the embedded broker provided by the framework,

Comment: Do I understand correctly - if I add `@KafkaListener ` to service and try run `UnitTest`(Or integration test in this case: @SpringBootTest) - SpringBootTest load context and can not connect to Kafka and fail?

Answer (score 1):

By default, when the application context loads, the framework will `start()` the listener container for the listener.

You can set the `autoStartup` property to `false` to prevent the container from starting.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "test", groupId = "v-group", autoStartup = "false")
public void test(){
  log.info("test");
}
```